# Side bar menu icon is invisible in Tab bar based view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I've implemented side bar using SWRevealViewController. But when i do same using Tab bar based view controller, menu icon is invisible only in tab based screens.
Icon is visible in interface builder but invisible in simulator/device.
Functionality is working in every screen, even in tab based view controller.
When i drag from left to right and vice versa, functionality is working fine.
Only the issue is menu icon is invisible in simulator.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

below is the swift file for tab

```
import UIKit

class ItemOneViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var menuBar: UIBarButtonItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setMenuBarBtn(menuBar: menuBar)

    navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.color(.blue)
}

func setMenuBarBtn(menuBar: UIBarButtonItem) {
    menuBar.target = revealViewController()
    menuBar.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}

func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
}
```

Code is similar for three tabs.

I've done below tasks before asking question here

1. Deleted and recreated screens two times.
2. Cross checked everything and compared tab bar based scenes source code with other scenes.
3. googled it.

Below are the images for your reference

[Tab based screen with side bar functionality (working good)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTzrg.png)

[Tab based screen without menu icon (Problem persist here , i want menu icon to be displayed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLoJt.png)

[HomeScreen with menu icon (Working good)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sISud.png)

[Navigation Controller attribute inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz9rA.png)

[my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaAPz.png)

[Item One View Controller view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHXSD.png)

[Item One view Controller related navigation controller scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC1Sc.png)

Comment: try adding these lines in viewDidlayoutSubViews     
setMenuBarBtn(menuBar: menuBar)     navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.color(.blue)

Comment: No, it is not working @AbuUlHassan

Comment: if you hide tabbar button appears or not ?

Comment: i didn't hide anything , it is button item and i can see it in interface builder, invisible in simulator/real device

Comment: i got your issue...  give me a minute

Comment: Can you please attach screen shot of your navigation bar of Document outline for ItemOneViewController from storyboard??

Comment: document outline means view hierarchy of navigation bar.

Comment: you will not be able to do it like the way you are doing as if you do like this you have to init swRevealViewController for all navigationController in tabbar

Comment: I've edited my question and you can have a look to images which you asked @AbuUlHassan

Comment: i got this but you are in need to do some custom code in your tabbar controller ....

Comment: Can you please tell me the best approach to get desired result

Comment: i have posted an answer  check it.

Answer (score 0):

You gave to add normal button on HomeViewController [image]

Then directly perform segue through storyboard(from burger menu button).

```
@IBAction func sideMenuBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "sideMenu", sender: self)
    }
```

[image]
Then on SideMenuController :

```
import UIKit
import SideMenu

class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var sideMenuTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            SideMenuManager.default.menuPresentMode = .menuSlideIn
            SideMenuManager.default.menuFadeStatusBar = false
            SideMenuManager.default.menuWidth = self.view.frame.width / 1.4
            SideMenuManager.default.menuShadowOpacity = 0.3
            sideMenuTableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
      }
 }
```

Comment: Will that don't work with button item? Everything works fine , but only the menu icon is invisible in simulator/real device

Comment: That is normal view (not navigation bar) and this is also normal button not button item.
About Button Item I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a tabbarController class like below, and assign this ViewController class to tabbar on storyboard ... 
**I have not tested this code but something like this should work for your case**

```
class ViewController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let firstSw = setRootViewControllerFor(identifier: "firstViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
    let secondsw = setRootViewControllerFor(identifier: "secondViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
    let thirdSw = setRootViewControllerFor(identifier: "thirdController") as! SWRevealViewController
    self.viewControllers = [firstSw,secondsw, thirdSw]
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func setRootViewControllerFor(identifier:String)->SWRevealViewController
{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sw") as! SWRevealViewController
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw
    let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationController!)
    navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden=false
    navigationController.setNavigationTints()        //call your UI method to set 
    sw.setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
    return sw
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

**OR Following by doing this there is no need to create a tabbarController**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // create UIWindow with the same size as main screen
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    // create story board. Default story board will be named as Main.storyboard in your project.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    // create view controllers from storyboard
    // Make sure you set Storyboard ID for both the viewcontrollers in 
    // Interface Builder -> Identitiy Inspector -> Storyboard ID
    let firstSw = setRootViewControllerFor(identifier: "firstViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
    let secondsw = setRootViewControllerFor(identifier: "secondViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
    let thirdSw = setRootViewControllerFor(identifier: "thirdController") as! SWRevealViewController

    // Set up the Tab Bar Controller to have two tabs
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    tabBarController.viewControllers =  [firstSw,secondsw, thirdSw]

    // Make the Tab Bar Controller the root view controller
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}


 func setRootViewControllerFor(identifier:String)->SWRevealViewController
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sw") as! SWRevealViewController
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw
        let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationController!)
        navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden=false
        navigationController.setNavigationTints()        //call your UI method to set 
        sw.setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
        return sw
    }
```

Comment: This one also didn't work for me instead i've seen unexpected result i.e tabs at bottom has gone.  I've used both the ways you suggested.

Comment: both solutions ?

Comment: then the last solution is you need to set swRevealViewController from storyboard

Comment: set SwRevealController  like you have set in HomeScreen with menu icon (Working good)  but instead of making home controller as root make tabbar as rootController

Comment: But, i need to show the Homescreen first to user. HomeScreen is the first screen, i can't change as it is not good approach.

Comment: and you need sidebar too on home screen ?

Comment: I need side bar in every screen through out the app and bottom tabs as well.

Comment: then what i am suggesting will work fine when you set revealViewControll as initial controller and set tabbar as root controller ... set Home at firstController of tabbar what the big deal ? or you can upload your project somewhere so that i can help you out.

Comment: Thanks- i will let you know when i complete as you suggested